# Site bem posicionado

Tags: html, html5, seo

Bom tenho um site no qual desenvolvi e gostaria que ele ficasse bem posicionado no Google já coloquei as meta tags etc. mas não adiantou muito gostaria de saber como fazer para que isso de certo e o site seja bem posicionado nas pesquisas, já ouvir falar em seo já pesquisei mas n ajudou muito.

Comment: Sem nem ter ideia sobre do que se trata o site, que tipo de informação há nele e como essa informação está estruturada, fica difícil dar uma resposta que não esteja apenas repetindo isso que você pesquisou sobre CEO.

Comment: Existe vasto material na internet que aborda esse assunto. São muitos os fatores que fazem o Google rankear um site. Digamos que Site A e Site B tratam de video-game. Por que o Site A é melhor rankeado que Site B quando eu busco por "video-game" no Google? Resposta: várias coisas. O Site A pode estar há mais tempo no ar, tem melhor conteúdo, atende aos critérios do Google melhor que o Site B, possui uma boa otimização SEO etc etc.

Comment: complementando o comentário do  Dvdsamm, etc, etc, etc, e ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O uso do sitemap.xml é uma das alternativas para mehorar o posicionamento do site nos buscadores. A principal função do Sitemap.xml é ajudar na indexação das páginas e categorias de um site.

Se o site possui um grande volume de páginas, categorias, subcategorias, produtos e subprodutos, com certeza o sitemap.xml será um grande facilitador para que o robô de busca (Google) encontre cada uma dessas páginas.

É importante lembrar que o Sitemap.xml nunca irá resolver tudo sozinho. Ele sempre deve ser acompanhado de uma boa arquitetura de links internos fazendo com que o robô de busca (Google) encontre e indexe mais páginas, além, claro, de acelerar o processo de indexação de novas páginas, caso seu site seja modificado com frequência. Você pode criar um Sitemap.xml através de um gerador de Sitemap.xml (para iniciantes). Eu recomendo o [Gerador de Sitemaps](https://www.ciawebsites.com.br/ferramentas-de-seo/gerador-de-sitemap/) da CIA WebSites.

Para melhorar o SEO de seu site, siga estas dicas:

1. Crie um sitemap XML
2. Inscreva o seu sitemap XML no Google

Para inscrever o seu sitemap XML no Google, você pode seguir [este tutorial](https://www.ecommercebrasil.com.br/artigos/como-criar-um-sitemap-e-cadastra-lo-no-google/) da ecommercebrasil